# Onclick attribute with if statement

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
click1=document.getElementById("job1");
click2=document.getElementById("job2");
if (click1.onclick) {
    x=1;
    store(x);
} else {
    x=2;
    store(x);
}
```

Why won't this work and instead loads the next function without clicking?

Comment: What does it even mean? You want to check for the presence of an onclick function?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: `if (click1.onclick)` does not do what you think it does - read up js events and closures, you'll need both here

Comment: Neither do you explain, what you intend to do, nor is your code in some way self exlanatory.

Comment: `click1.onclick` is `undefined`

Comment: As Dave said , I wan to check for the presence of onclick of two buttons

Comment: That's not actually what I said, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this instead:

```
click1=document.getElementById("job1");
click2=document.getElementById("job2");
click1.onclick= function() {
    x=1;
    store(x);
}
click2.onclick = function() {
    x=2;
    store(x);
}
```

Comment: Hi, the click2 is not working I wonder if it only run click1?

Comment: Does it matter if click 1 and click 2 are from different html?